# createthread in WinCE

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, windows-ce, createthread

I have this code written in MFC as a win32 application:

CZoneThread* pThread    = new CZoneThread( sZoneInfo );
pThread->CreateThread();

Here, CZoneThread is another class.

Will this code work correctly in WinCE as well?

Comment: There's not enough info to say. All that is possible to say is that CE allows programming in C++ and MFC and that it has threads. Whether your code works is impossible to tell without seeing the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could always try it - that would be a way to test it for yourself.  But yes, that will work fine under CE (well as fine as MFC ever works anyway).